# Using the Parse API (parse.com) with ember.js models

Tags: backbone.js, ember.js, javascript-framework, parse-platform

My goal is to implement an Ember.js front end with a Parse backend. I am reading in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide) for Parse that it is based on backbone.js and can easily be integrated into a backbone app with little code change.

> Our JavaScript SDK is based on the popular Backbone.js framework. It is compatible with existing Backbone applications with minimal changes on your part.

Question is, **can Parse objects be as easily integrated into an Ember app? If so, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look how they've solved the combination of Ember and Parse.com at [Neptune](https://github.com/bwship/neptunejs). It claims to be a

> baseline project meant to provide a solid foundation to build upon the Node/Ember/Parse stack

However I doubt you'll be able to integrate Parse objects into Ember app **as** easily as with Backbone, but it certainly seems doable.

Answer (score 5):

There have been a lot of updates to my Ember Data Adapter for Parse: http://clintjhill.github.com/ember-parse-adapter/

Comment: That one does not work with the latest Ember Data, but it has been almost 9 months since the above comment, so I'm not sure if the project is still maintained.

Comment: @EduárdMoldován theirs quite a few pull requests so the interest is defo there.

Answer (score 1):

http://clint-hill.com/2012/12/17/ember-parse-data-adapter/ is an Ember adapter for Parse (I have not used it, but would be curious to hear how well it works).

Comment: I've briefly checked this out, looks promising.